# Save DOMDocument problem (maybe use cURL?)

Tags: php, curl, domdocument

I currently have a very simple news system that reads in RSS from a local file using `DOMDocument->load()`.  In addition there is a very simple back end that adds items to the loaded feed and saves it back using `DOMDocument->save()`.

This works fine on my testing server, but when deployed to the client the save operation fails with a 500 error.  I think this is due to limitations they have in place which also prevent use of `fopen` and `file_get_contents`, although I'm confused by how I can load the XML fine, but not save it back again.

So really I have two questions (naughty, I know):

1. Does DOMDocument's save method differ substantially from load, and what is the underlying technique used to write the file?
2. How would I go about saving a DOMDocument object as XML using cURL (because I know cURL is permitted)?

For what it's worth, here is a truncated version of the load/save:

```
//load the xml
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/news_rss.xml');
$doc->formatOutput = true;
//add some stuff to the xml ...

//save it again
$doc->save($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/news_rss.xml');
```

Comment: *(protip)* Look at your error logs instead of assuming. The reason for the error will be in there. And you will likely find that it's not DOM related at all.

Comment: Sadly I don't have access to those, and the IT people that do are incredibly slow to respond. I was hoping to have a workable solution ready to present when I do finally hear from them again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

curl and dom don't have much to do with each other. Curl just fetches a specified resource (or sends data to a resource). DOM parses xml/html trees. The fact that you can point dom at a particular URL and get that url's contents is a byproduct of PHP's file-based functions allowing URLs.

There's no link between DOM and CURL, so you can't have DOM invoke curl to fetch/save for you. You'd have to use CURL to fetch some resource and save it into a temporary file (or a variable), then use that file/variable as a source in DOM. The same goes vice version - DOM cannot invoke curl to save a file.

Given that your load/save calls aren't using URLs (just a local file path), I'd check permissions on the news_rss.xml file. Generally most files on a system are readable by everyone, but not everyone has write permissions.

Comment: Right you are.  When I finally hear back from the client's IT department, it turns out they have blocked dynamic writing of XML files as a security measure. Amazingly the file still shows as writable, but somewhere along the line the server decides to throw a 500 instead.